# How to reference a custom field to content type entry

Tags: 7, nodes

In Drupal 7 I've created a "Products" content type and a custom module that creates an entity "Orders" with a field "Products".

I want to reference my field "Products" with the products from the content type.
Any suggestions how to make it pro grammatically?

Comment: Is there a reason you're re-writing the Commerce module from scratch?